# Ubuntu 20.04 on VMWare 16.1.2 - no internet connection with NAT

Tags: networking, 20.04, docker, vmware-workstation, nat

I have couple Ubuntu VMs - 20.04.1 and 20.04.2. Both are set for NAT connection. Both have identical setting except 20.04.1 has Docker installed and 20.04.2 has Minikube.

Both at one point had internet connections. I am not sure if that is related to recent upgrade to Workstation 16.1.2  but right now 20.04.2 still connects fine but 20.04.01 boots up without internet connection at all. Even though "Network Adapter" in status bar shows status as "NAT" and  "Connected".
Is there a canonical way to debug it?

PS> My settings in VMWare "Edit>Virtual network Editor" are default for NAT. And I believe that that they are global and one VM connects and the other suddenly stopped. If that is Docker related then I need to know how to resolve because I need Docker for my project.